# Redirect all urls ending in "/"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all URLs ending in "/" to urls that don't end in "/".

Example:

```
domain.com/            -> domain.com
domain.com/page1/      -> domain.com/page1
domain.com/category1/  -> domain.com/category1
domain.com///          -> domain.com
```

I've tried the following approaches, but none work:

- `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/+$ http:\/\/www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
- `RewriteRule (.*)\/+$ http:\/\/www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}[?\s]
RewriteRule ^$ / [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I copied and pasted, not working. I placed it at the end of the file, at the beginning, middle and nothing.

Comment: The index of the page when you put: domain.com/////

Comment: No, it has the same behavior

Comment: It works to perfection, just what we needed. Thank you for supporting @anubhava.